# How to use both will_paginate AND filters with Tire (Elastic Search)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

It looks like I can use one or the other but not both, anyone have an example of how to do this?  The issue is, that in order to use will_paginate, I have to use the search method in a model

```
Item.search("test", :page => 1, :per_page => 20)
```

but in order to use filters, I have to use Tire directly:

```
search = Tire::Search::Search.new("items")
search.filter :term, :selected => true
```

But I cannot find out how to do both.   Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use this library yet, but as far as I can make out from the source code, Model#search and Tire::Search::Search should take the same options. If you look at the source code of Model#search it does this (reduced to relevant parts):

```
def search(*args, &block)

  query, options = args

  s = Tire::Search::Search.new(options.delete(:index), options)
```

so options is just handed through to the initializer of Tire::Search::Search.

But this is only creating the object. Tire::Search::Search seems internally to use the terms `size` and `from` instead of `per_page` and `page`. So the above code continues like this:

```
  page     = options.delete(:page)
  per_page = options.delete(:per_page) || Tire::Results::Pagination::default_per_page

  s.size( per_page.to_i ) if per_page
  s.from( page.to_i <= 1 ? 0 : (per_page.to_i * (page.to_i-1)) ) if page && per_page
```

so it seems `from` works different from `page` (while `size` and `per_page` are similar). `from` is an absolute position. (I don't know what exactly Tire::Results::Pagination::default_per_page adds here, maybe some default that can be set.)

To come to a conclusion, my educated guess would be that something like this should work for you:

```
search = Tire::Search::Search.new("items", size: 20, from: 0)
```

where for other pages positions you would calculate (per_page * (page - 1))